# How do I secure my Content Management System?

Tags: authentication, content-management-system

How should I go about securing my Content Management System? It's entirely self-contained in a folder on the server, but I'm unsure about how to make it secure. Obviously, it's a pretty sensitive thing. I'd prefer not to use PHP, but if that's the only option then that's okay.

Thanks for any help on the subject.

Comment: What do you mean make it secure? Could you please clarify? If it is joomla or something, then you should not be worried about security in its codebase. Cause its a long time its around and many security implementation has been made. If you mean, you wanna restrict others accessing those files in that folder directly, you could try htaccess (tell me if it is the case, so that i tell you how to do that)

Answer (score 1):

You can use apache .htaccess to protect access to files with password.

For example

```
<Files administrator.php>
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Enter the password"
 AuthUserFile /path/to/file/.htpasswd
 Require valid-user
</Files>
```

You have to generate a .htpasswd file with username and password hash (http://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator), place in a directory not visible from web and change the path in AuthUserFile.

Comment: So just the presence of the .htacess and .htpasswd files will stop people from viewing the page without the passcode given in .htpasswd?

Comment: Yes, this apache directives block access to a file/folder unless you provide the password. Just make sure it is .htaccess (double 'c') and test to make sure that your hosting/server supports this config.

Answer (score 0):

If your CMS is stored in a folder on a server, you can create security on the folder level. Try right-clicking the folder and choosing 'Security' tab and set the appropriate permission.

Cheers.